# Android Analytics Campaign Tracking

Tags: android, api, google-analytics, analytics

I want to know how my android users are getting to the play store link of my app.
To do this I have integrated the Google Analytics API, but the installation intent isn't called and I can't get the utm_source, utm_campaign ... parameters in the link built with the [google play url builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-campaigns)

So i'm trying to do this with my custom intent like this :

1: The android manifest :

```
<receiver android:name="com.appehour.InstallReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"  android:exported="true"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

2: the InstallReceiver class

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String 
    utm_compaign , 
    utm_source, 
    utm_medium, 
    utm_term, 
    utm_content,
    deviceId;

private static String url, installTimeStamp;
public static final String PREF_TRACK_INSTALL_RECEIVER_DATAS = "datas_receiver_install",
        PREF_DEVICE_ID = "pref_device_id",
        PREF_COMPAIGN = "pref_compaign",
        PREF_SOURCE = "pref_source",
        PREF_MEDIUM = "pref_medium",
        PREF_TERM = "pref_term",
        PREF_CONTENT = "pref_content",
        PREF_INSTALL_TIME_STAMP = "pref_install_time_stamp",
        PREF_DATA_STORED = "pref_datas_stored";

protected JSONObject jsonSend , jsonObjRecv;
private boolean installParamsSend = false;



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

    installTimeStamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) ;
    deviceId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);


    //****************************** Tris des datas reçus par le brodcast ********************************//

    String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");

    //the paramters are separated by this : %3D
    // uriTokens store all the paramaters with her value
    String[] uriTokens = referrer.split("%3D");
    for(int i=0;i<uriTokens.length;i++){

        //the parameter name and the value are separated 
        String[] valTokens = uriTokens[i].split("%26");

        if (valTokens[0].equals("utm_compaign"))
            utm_compaign = valTokens[1];
        else if (valTokens[0].equals("utm_source"))
            utm_source = valTokens[1];
        else if (valTokens[0].equals("utm_medium"))
            utm_medium = valTokens[1];
        else if (valTokens[0].equals("utm_term"))
            utm_term = valTokens[1];
        else if (valTokens[0].equals("utm_content"))
            utm_content = valTokens[1];
    }


    //******************************************************************************************************//

    Log.d(InstallReceiver.this.getClass().getSimpleName(), 
            "utm_compaign = "+utm_compaign+
            "| utm_source = "+utm_source+
            "| utm_medium = "+utm_medium+
            "| utm_term = "+utm_term+
            "| utm_content = "+utm_content+
            "| device_id = "+deviceId+
            "| installTimeStamp ="+installTimeStamp);
```

When I simulate the app installation with adb shell:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.appehour.jdm/com.appehour.InstallReceiver --es  "referrer" "utm_source%26testSource%3Dutm_compaign%268656"
```

I get my data. But when I put my app on the store, the data are not recovered.

Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: Hey there, have you found what was the problem ?

Comment: No , Sorry, i don't know

Comment: Does it work if you use the default CampaignTrackingReceiver? Note also you've got a typo: utm_compaign should be utm_campaign.